# How to float items to left and right without wrappers?

Tags: css, position

Here is some example code: http://jsfiddle.net/cKTtu/

I want the items with class `left` to float at left and the ones with class `right` to float at right (next to the left ones). How can I achieve it without wrapper divs?

Comment: any specific reason u want to avoid wrapper divs?

Comment: Like this? [your JSFiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/cKTtu/1/)

Comment: Are you trying to create a two column layout with left floated items in the first column and the right floated items in the second column?

Comment: Can we have a look at your code? Because there is many way to do it. For example: both items floated left and the left one you add margin-right or padding-right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your left and right floats aren't lined up, but LinkinTED's are (in the JSFiddle he linked from his comment), is that order matters in the declaration of floating DIVs. Floating elements, just like non-floating elements, are first positioned as part of a top-to-bottom "flow" on the page. Then they are taken out of their natural position in the flow and moved horizontally to the left or right until they encounter either the edge of their containing element or the edge of another floating element.

Therefore, when you have three DIVs with the `float:left` property declared one after the other, they will naturally be positioned one after the other, and before the two  `float:right` DIVs declared after them. When they are pulled out of the flow to float to the left, they will still maintain this order. Ordinarily, the three left-floating elements would stack up horizontally (the second one would float to the edge of the first one), but since each one also has the `clear:left` property, the subsequent DIVs are forced onto their own lines. Only after the three left-floating DIVs are positioned can the two right-floating DIVs appear, because they appear later in the natural (pre-floated) flow.

On the other hand, LinkinTED's JSFiddle declares the DIVs in the order of alternating right and left, so that in the natural flow they would appear interleaved. Then when each right-floating DIV is pulled out of the flow to float right, it can share a line with the left-floating DIV because no other left-floating DIV needs to appear yet.

For more information on float mechanics, check out [this page](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/) and [this page](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/introduction.htm).